# Redefine Virtual Functions between header files in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have one header file which uses a virtual function.

This is declared and defined:

```
#ifndef HeaderH
#define HeaderH

class Base {
<some code>  
public:virtual int checkVal(int& val) { return val;} 
};
#endif
```

I have another header file which declares some functions, and inherits from this base header.

Finally, I have the implementation of this header file in another .cpp file:
I want to override the virtual function checkVal in my implementation here, but I keep getting a redefinition error.

```
int Base::checkVal(int&  value)
{
  if(value == 0)
        value = 10;
  return value;
}
```

Is there something I should include in my header file which will override the Base virtual function?

Comment: I think where you say you want to override the base you actually want to create a specific implementation for your child class (the one defined in the second header) change to int Child::check(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already provided the definition of `checkval()` inside your base class, so why are you redefining it? You can define it only once.If you want to give the implementation inside the `.cpp` file, just declare `checkval()` inside the base class, no need to define it there.

Your implementation of `checkval()` fails if you call it like the following:

```
Base b;
//some code
b.checkval(10);//Error because temporaries cannot be bound to non-constant references
```

> Is there something I should include in my header file which will override the Base virtual function?

Create a derived class inside the header file and override `checkval()` then by declaring the function inside the derived class and defining it inside `.cpp` file.

Comment: I have several classes which use the Base Header file, so I need the definition of this function here. Anywhere else and it would mean huge rework to update all inheriting classes. My code works as Base.h <- Another.h <- Class.cpp. For this class, I need to override the functionality of the standard Base.h function, so I made it virtual to override it in the .cpp. Is this possible?

Comment: Overriding means redefining a function(same signature) in the derived class. Create a derived class and redefine `checkval()` inside it.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined the function as `{ return val;}` in the header file, you can't also define it as

```
{
     if(value == 0)
        value = 10;
     return value;
}
```

anywhere else in your program.  It can only have one definition.  It may be that you meant the second definition to be for a derived class (and not Base), but that's not what you have in your code.  The fact that your question doesn't use the word class at all tells me you might be confused about how virtual functions work.  Read up on them some, it should be pretty obvious how to define a virtual function in a derived class.

It should look something like `Derived::checkVal(int & value)`.  note the use of "Derived" as the class name instead of "Base".

Comment: I have several classes which use the Base Header file, so I need the definition of this function here. Anywhere else and it would mean huge rework to update all inheriting classes.

My code works as Base.h <- Another.h <- Class.cpp. 

For this class, I need to override the functionality of the standard Base.h function, so I made it virtual to override it in the .cpp.

Is this possible?

I hope this clears any confusion up..

Answer (score 2):

xxx.h

```
#ifndef HeaderH
#define HeaderH

class Base {
  virtual int checkVal(int& val); // no definition 
};
#endif
```

xxx.cpp

```
#include "xxx.h"

int Base::checkVal(int&  value)
{
    if (value == 0)
      value = 10;
    return value;
}
```

And it works fine. Else the compiler will not know what definition to use. *There can be only one!*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you mean overriding. And your implementation is missing a return type - it should be:

```
int Base::checkVal(int&  value)
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the complete code illustrating what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You have two implementations in your Base class, one in the header file, the other in the .cpp file. Just omit the one in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

The error is exactly what you should get.

Without creating a new class that inherits from Base, you cannot redefine the function.

```
#ifndef DERIVED_H
#define DERIVED_H

#include "base.h"

class Derived : public Base{
<some code>  
public:
    virtual int checkVal(int& val)
    { 
       if(value == 0)
          value = 10;
       return value;
    } 
};
#endif DERIVED_H
```

Then use `Derived` where you were going to use `Base`.
Please read [Friendship and Inheritance](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/).